# Output is not proper in angular.js file

Tags: angularjs

I have written this code

```
   <html ng-app>
   <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script>
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.username = 'World';

   $scope.sayHello = function() {
   $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
 };
}]); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
 Your name:
<input type="text" ng-model="username">
<button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
<hr>
 {{greeting}}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In place of taking input from text box it's just printing {{greeting}} and even the text box is not initialized with world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app tag module name is missing you can put ng-app="scopeExample" in your html.

```
<html ng-app="scopeExample">
```

it is required to bootstrap angular
ref:-
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 1):

set on top html tag `ng-app ="scopeExample"`

Answer (score 0):

Define your ng-app="scopeExample", [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/qrzfsLv5/).

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.username = 'World';

   $scope.sayHello = function() {
   $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
 };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function HelloCntl($area) {
    $area.test= 'Demo';
}
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  Your name: <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
  <hr/>
  Hello {{test|| "Demo"}}!
</div>
```

## You Can Try This Code I check this code is properly working and i am also using this code